# eliminar espacio de los nombres de una variable en r

Tags: r

Tengo una variable (una columna) con nombres y apellidos. Quiero eliminar el espacio entre el nombre y el apellido.

¿Como lo puedo hacer, sin que se conviertan todos los campos de mi matriz en factores?

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que pusieras parte del código y que nos dijeras de que lenguaje se trata, mas información en [ask]

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta, estaría bien que la validases :)

Answer (score 4):

Puede ayudarte `gsub(" ", "", tu_string)`.

Esta funcion remplaza coincidencias dentro de una cadena. El primer parametro es el lo que quieres reemplazar, en este caso el espacio en blanco `" "`, el segundo parametro es porque valor quieres reemplazar el primero, en este caso `""` y el tercero es tu cadena.

Te dejo un link con mas ejemplos sobre esta funcion, esta en ingles pero el traductor de google basta para entender.

[Gsub Ejemplos](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php)